# FireFox webdriver error

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

python code is not able to locate the geckodriver .

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox('D:/Folder_1/chrome_driver/geckodriver_win32/geckodriver.exe')
```

error: WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid:'D:/Folder_1/chrome_driver/geckodriver_win32/geckodriver.exe/*.*'

Comment: only 2 backward slashes , **'D:\\geckodriver.exe'** if on windows

Comment: actaul path is :D:/Folder_1/chrome_driver/geckodriver_win32/geckodriver.exe

Comment: Do this
`browser=webdriver.Firefox('D:\\Folder_1\\chrome_driver\\geckodriver_win32\\geckodriver.exe')`

Comment: i have tried  using "r" ,but am getting the same error

Comment: i have updated my comment, check above. Another easy solution would be to place the geckodriver.exe in the same folder as your script.

Comment: thanks for your help,but that updated code is also not working

Answer (score 5):

In windows, you need to put path in attribute `executable_path`

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\\Folder_1\\chrome_driver\\geckodriver_win32\\geckodriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 1):

if in window, you need add the `geckodriver.exe` path in you sys path. and
useing

```
from selenium import webdriver
bow = webdriver.Firefox()
```